# Increment integer MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have looked through many of the questions already asked on here but have not yet found one that I can adapt to my own situation.

I currently have a table filled with values that are used for dropdowns on various webpages I have assembled. I am attempting to add support for SMS messaging. To do this I have added a column to my table of dropdown values called SMSID. This value needs to be an integer from 0-999 unique to a specific dropdown.

So for instance, I have an html select with multiple options, I want each option to have a uniqueID from 0-999 alphabetically, loaded from the database.

Is there a way to use an update statement to go through every record and add a uniqueID for each dropdown option?

I.E.

Table example:

```
    FoodType | ingredients | smsID
    Pizza    | pepperoni   | 003
    Pizza    | onions      | 002
    Pizza    | mushrooms   | 000
    Pizza    | olives      | 001
    Sandwich | ham         | 000
    Sandwich | roast beef  | 001
    Sandwich | turkey      | 002
```

Comment: change the `smsID` column to `IDENTITY`

Comment: If I understand you right - you need to distinctly enumerate all your ingredients in specific food type. If so, you should have a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on `FoodType,smsID`, and yes - there is a way to do that in update statement using window function concatenated with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT FoodType, Ingredients, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FoodType ORDER BY FoodType) AS smsID
FROM dbo.Dropdowns
```

Answer (score 2):

The CTE update method is much faster than subqueries or self-joins

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/347fc/2)

```
;WITH t(old,new) AS (
  SELECT
    smsID
   ,REPLACE(STR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FoodType ORDER BY ingredients)-1,3),' ','0')
  FROM MyTable
)
UPDATE t
SET old = new
```

Comment: I do prefer the idea of a faster executing query as the table I am using is actually 400000~ records. However, I do receive an error message upon trying this approach. 

Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '***' to data type int.

Comment: "This value needs to be an integer from 0-999 unique to a specific dropdown" <- You may need to revisit this requirement.  The function `STR(n,3)` will return `'***'` when `n > 999`.  Your data apparently has at least one FoodType with more than 1000 ingredients.

Comment: It has been a while but you are correct. The data I had given in regards to food type was to avoid giving out confidential information. The answer I ended up using included changes to allow a hex conversion for more options.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to number your rows.

```
SELECT FoodType, ingredients,
    ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY FoodType ORDER BY ingredients) smsID
FROM dropdowns
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fed58/5/0

```
UPDATE ft
SET smsID= RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row-1),3)
FROM foodtype ft
inner join (
  select
    Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY FoodType ORDER BY ingredients ASC) [Row],
    *
  FROM FoodType
) a ON a.FoodType=ft.FoodType AND a.ingredients=ft.ingredients
```